# Install php8.1-zip, gdl,intl on Ubuntu 18.04 failed

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-extension

i tried to install the following extensions:
php8.1-zip, php8.1-gdl,php8.1-intl
on Ubuntu 18.04

Previously i could install the php8.1 package by

```
sudo apt install php8.1
```

but after trying to install the extensions(zip, gdl,intl) :

```
sudo apt install php8.1-zip
```

i got error:

```
a required part of the software package is outdated, unavailable or missing
```

Alternately i tried to install php8.0 but after intall and run:

```
sudo a2enmode php8.0
```

i got :
ERROR: Module php8.0 does not exist!

What cause the problem? i know that Ubuntu 18.04 is not supported anymore, but its not a properly time to upgrade the whole system now

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 never came with PHP 8 native. Where are you installing it from?

Comment: thank you @AlexHowansky, i can not exactly tell you the from i have just used the regular command: sudo apt install php8.1, and the basic extension were installed as well

Comment: You're likely using the `ppa:ondrej/php` repository, which is no longer maintained for Ubuntu 18.04. You might be able to [install from PECL source](https://pecl.php.net/package/zip).